# Geometric probabilities solution verification

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification

> An unbiased coin is tossed until a head appears and then tossed until a tail appears. If the tosses are independent, what is the probability that a total of exactly n tosses will be required?

**My attempt:**

P($n$ tosses required to produce one head and one tail) $=$ P($x$ tosses needed for first head) $\times$ P($y$ tosses needed for first tail) where $x+y=n$.

So, the probability becomes
$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x-1} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{y-1} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}
\end{align}$$
This is not the correct answer, however. The correct answer is $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n} \cdot (n-1)$. Can someone pleas explain what I did incorrectly and where the $n-1$ factor is coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thinking is almost there - except in your argument, $x$ could be anything from $1$ to $n-1$ (since getting a head on $x$th toss and then getting a tail on the $y = n - x$th toss gives you a head and tail on exactly the $n$th toss). So if we sum your expression over all possible combinations of $x$ and $y = n-x$, we have $n - 1$ times the expression you got.

More generally, this is an example of (a variant of) the [Negative Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution), which counts the number of successes needed for $r$ events to happen.

Comment: The issue was that I did not even realize that something (here: the $n-1$ factor) was missing in my answer. Is there a way to realize this without using the NB distribution directly?

Comment: To be more precise, your expression would be correct if we add in $\sum_{x=1}^{n-1} ...$ to the front, to account for all the different combinations that can happen. Note that $y = n - x$ necessarily, so it only depends on $x$. Then if we count there are $n - 1$ combinations, and each one occurs with the same probability.